# Youtube link and get method

Tags: php, string, replace, youtube, str-replace

Trying not to go to youtube for every video I find on some other site, and that is from youtube.
If I right click and copy video URL, url will have this feature stuff inside the link, I am trying to get rid of that with str_replace.

Link `http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wq7ftOZBy0E`

```
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('feature=player_embedded&', '', $_GET['link']);
```

or

```
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?', $_GET['link']);
```

Either will return only `http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded`, instead of what I am expecting: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq7ftOZBy0E`

**UPDATE:**

I realized this is not problem in str_replace as I thought on first, looks like if url is

```
http://localhost/mysite/link.php/?link=http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wq7ftOZBy0E
```

$_GET['link'] uses url till "&". It is missing all this `&v=wq7ftOZBy0E`.

Seems like ampersand broke $_GET['link'], what can I do to make this work?

**Solution, based on accepted answer:**

```
if(isset($_GET['v']))
{
$_GET['link'] = $_GET['link'].'&v='.$_GET['v'];
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('feature=player_embedded&', '', $_GET['link']);
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('http://youtu.be/', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
echo $_GET['link'];
}
else
{
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
$_GET['link'] = str_replace('http://youtu.be/', '//www.youtube.com/embed/', $_GET['link']);
echo $_GET['link'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following code

```
if(isset($_GET['v']))
{
$resultURL=$_GET['link'].'&v='.$_GET['v'];
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's it. I made this all code from it: http://pastebin.com/inKj4bHB Going to test it now. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code

```
<?php
$_GET['link']="http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=wq7ftOZBy0E";

echo $_GET['link'] = str_replace('feature=player_embedded&', '', $_GET['link']);

?>
```

And i got the following ouput

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq7ftOZBy0E

I dont know what you are looking for

Comment: You make me think, and I tried your code alone. I saw it works. I updated question.

Comment: You can get the data as $_GET['v']

Comment: Can't use that. My function is not only for youtube. I have to work with $_GET['link'], as I use videos from various sites. I need to make that ampersand not stoping $_GET.

Comment: Then what is the thing you want to have finally...I mean what is the final output you want to have

Comment: I have "link.php" file with iframe and inside is function for $_GET['link'], works for everything, just this ampersand is blocking $_GET to take everything after http://localhost/mysite/link.php/?link= for youtube only.

Comment: Yeah i Got your problem for youtube you are getting two query strings one is 'link' and another is 'v'.Then you have to append your data which you are getting after &

Comment: you can use like this $_GET['link']=$_GET['link'].'&v='.$_GET['v'].I will make you the code you can check that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $id =  substr($_GET['link'],-11);
```

This will give you the youtube video id (the unique string after 'v=-------',Youtube ids are 11 digit random strings).

Comment: That method will always go -11, and my function is not only for youtube, it is iframe for all videos and any site, and also is to large for posting here. Probably no one would read it. Even if I paste all, it will not be understandable. Looks like problem is in $_GET and not in string replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data which is after & as $_GET['v'].

Which simply gets the data assigned to the variable 'v'